# Lazy loading / caching Ruby model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, lazy-loading

I'm storing user session keys in a Rails active record model in a column called *skey*. *skey* must be obtained every 10 minutes via an external API call, but until 10 minutes have elapsed I'd like to cache *skey* and return the cached value. Here's what I've got:

```
def skey_valid?
  (Time.now - self.skey_used_at) < 7.minutes
end

def skey
  if skey_valid? == false
    _skey = authenticate #external API call
    if _skey.nil?
      return nil
    end

    update_attribute :skey, _skey
  end

  update_attribute :skey_used_at, Time.now
  return self[:skey]
end
```

The problem is now when I call User.skey, it enters an infinite loop and stack overflows. Apparently when I execute update_attribute :skey, _skey, my custom *skey* function is called which again calls update_attribute :skey, _skey.

Any suggestions on how to get around this? Or if there's a better to approach to what I'm trying to do I'd love to know. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I maintain a gem called `volatile_hash` which does something similar for Hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `update_columns` instead of `update_attribute`. Update will directly issue update query instead of using the getter

```
def skey_valid?
  (Time.now - self.skey_used_at) < 7.minutes
end

def skey
  unless skey_valid?
    _skey = authenticate #external API call
    return nil unless _skey

    update_columns(:skey => _skey)
  end

  update_columns(:skey_used_at => Time.now)
  return read_attribute(:skey)
end
```

Comment: The same problem seems to happen with update(:skey => _skey) using the exact code you posted. If it matters at all I'm using Rails 4.0.0.

Comment: Modified my answer. I should have tested it. Sorry for that